# Check string is empty, white space or null Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am parsing CSV and checking if any item/string is empty/white space/null but none if the condition is not working!!

What I am doing wrong here?

[image: Compose]

Logic to check
[image: Condition]

**Scenario**

Parse CSV by each line and then by each column and check if string is empty/whitespace/null

If string is empty/whitespace/null

```
IscorrectCSV =False
```

Else

```
IscorrectCSV =True
```

**INPUT 1**

name,age
a1,34
a2,null
a3," "
a4,""
a5,"  4"
A6,

**EXPECTED OUTPUT 1**
IscorrectCSV =False

**INPUT 2**

name,age
a1,34
a2,35
a3,36

**EXPECTED OUTPUT 2**
IscorrectCSV =True

Comment: There’s a connector coming that you could use now through the HTTP action … www.statesolutions.com.au … will make your life a lot easier. The CSV to Json operation also accepts filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the empty and trim expression  together to find if the array item has some value

[image: empty expression]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need replace **and** instead of **OR**
remove first comparison and set variable before condition
First check if  is equal null
Secondly check if the formula length() is equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve this using below flow.

First I tried to form an Array from the sample csv given and then I used condition action inside a for-each loop to loop through second column item and check for the condition.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

You can reproduce the same in your logic app using the below code-view

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Array",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@skip(split(outputs('Compose'),'\n'),1)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "name,age\na1,34\na2,NULL\na3, \na4,''\na5,",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@variables('FinalArray')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "FinalArray": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "FinalArray",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "FinalArray",
                                    "value": "@{items('For_each')} - @{variables('IscorrectCSV')}"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Set_IscorrectCSV_-_False": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            },
                            "Set_IscorrectCSV_-_False": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "IscorrectCSV",
                                    "value": false
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Append_to_array_variable_2": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "name": "FinalArray",
                                        "value": "@{items('For_each')} - @{variables('IscorrectCSV')}"
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {
                                        "Set_IscorrectCSV_-_True": [
                                            "Succeeded"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                },
                                "Set_IscorrectCSV_-_True": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "name": "IscorrectCSV",
                                        "value": true
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "SetVariable"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "or": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@slice(items('For_each'),add(indexOf(items('For_each'),','),1),length(items('For_each')))",
                                        "NULL"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@slice(items('For_each'),add(indexOf(items('For_each'),','),1),length(items('For_each')))",
                                        " "
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@slice(items('For_each'),add(indexOf(items('For_each'),','),1),length(items('For_each')))",
                                        "''"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "lessOrEquals": [
                                        "@length(slice(items('For_each'),add(indexOf(items('For_each'),','),1),length(items('For_each'))))",
                                        0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "IscorrectCSV": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "IscorrectCSV": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "IscorrectCSV",
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "FinalArray": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```